# 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' error on indesign interop

Tags: c#, com, interop, adobe-indesign

Im trying make automated page design with Adobe InDesign CC.

this is my code in C# :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application");
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Adobe InDesign CC is not installed");
        }
        _Application app = (_Application)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        Document document = (Document)app.Documents.Add(true, missing);
        Page page = (Page)document.Pages[1];
        TextFrame textFrame = page.TextFrames.Add(missing,
           idLocationOptions.idUnknown, missing);
        textFrame.GeometricBounds = new string[] { "6p", "6p", "24p", "24p" };
        textFrame.Contents = "Hello from .Net!";
        return View();
    }
```

now when i run it gives this error to me :

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {FB6F0F4B-0467-4F63-88EC-3960B8E1B3EE} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

error happens in line :

```
_Application app = (_Application)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

this is the screenshot :

[image]

also , when i run this code , Adobe Indesign getting opened but do nothing happend until error shows up.

Comment: It is a very low-level error, Windows is convinced that it was not able to start the program.  If you actually see it starting then something went drastically wrong and somebody didn't do what it was supposed to do.  That somebody is *not* VS or your program or Windows.  Check if the program has an option that you need to set to explicitly enable automation.  Use the vendor's support channels to find help.

Comment: @HansPassant You were right. it was a problem with Adobe Indesign Installation.
after uninstalling CC and replace version with CS6 problem solved.